# Selecting Telephone Number JQuery does not select the first '0'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery selector which is supposed to select a telephone number from a data attribute when a link is clicked.

```
<a class="mobile" href="javascript:void(0);" data-mobile_p="064366554565">Send SMS</a>
```

When selected with the following,

```
$('.mobile').data('mobile_p');
alert(mobile);
```

The returned number is 64366554565 - without the beginning 0. Albeit I can then easily add another '0' to it but this does not seem good practice.

Comment: Hm, I'm getting the leading zero alright. Btw, could you provide whole code? This code is not complete.

Comment: Where (and how) is the data assigned to the variable `mobile`?

Comment: particular browser involved? On a fruitmachine, maybe?

Comment: the phone number is assigned to the data attribute via an ajax request. When the link (Send SMS) is clicked ($(document).on('click', '.mobile', function(){$('.mobile').data('mobile_p');
alert(mobile);});

Comment: @Sideshow This is definitely coming from somewhere else in your code. Are you storing this as a number or a string? If you strore it as a number (int, float, etc) then the zero would be assumed to be irrelevant and discarded. Just a thought, hope it helps. ;)

Comment: for now I have just added the extra 0 to the variable. I do however think that there is a conflict somewhere within the 3500 lines of script. As I am only prototyping I will probably debug this later as I have a bit of an urgent deadline on completeing the rest of the code. Thanks for your help )

Answer (score 2):

For me it works fine. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQDSf/1/)

```
$('.mobile').click(function () {
   var mobile = $(this).data('mobile_p');
   alert(mobile);
});
```

Comment: The number shows up fine in the data attr through firebug - it just looses the leading 0 in firefox 16

Comment: I tested on firefox 16.0.1 and works fine on it. It does not loose leading zero on both chrome and firefox

Answer (score -1):

Well, according to your comment, you are probably assigning variable mobile somewhere out of function scope.
Assign local variable inside.

```
$(document).on(
    'click', 
    '.mobile',
    function() {
        var mobile = $('.mobile').data('mobile_p'); 
        alert(mobile);
    }​);​
```

Comment: Not exactly. Please look at the part "var mobile =..."

Comment: Ah yes - spotted the difference - still omitting the first 0 though :( must be a quirk in my code somewhere else. Will have to investigate further. Thanks

Comment: Is there maybe another element with class mobile on the same document?